What is a significantly disabled person supposed to do if no Orthodox Jew will marry them?
I'll divide this question into 4 parts:
1.
If someone has a severe disability but cannot find an orthodox marriage partner, what in halacha are they expected to do regarding forbidden sexual activities? [This is not a question about whether they are obligated to have children.] For example, if someone has significant autism (level 2 ASD) and depression but is fully verbal and understand abstract concepts, what are they required to do regarding sexual and intimate needs? For example, are they allowed to be motzei zera levatala?
Some people assume that such people could not be happily married but such assumptions may be due to issues of stigma that prevent any possibility of Jewish marriage. Yet in reality such a person could be happily married. For example, an Orthodox Jewish social reject might marry a non-Jew because such a person might be willing to consider them as a marriage prospect in a way that religious Jews are not. And    such a marriage might be successful in showing that they are capable of intimacy, and in fact, are a pleasant person to live with.
2.
Suppose a Jew has autism and a progressive disease like some forms of painful multiple sclerosis which which makes their predicament worse each year. Suppose their deteriorating physical disability, makes them bed bound and unable to attend a Shul. Their pain makes their life very hard on an hour by hour basis. Are there any halachic leniencies regarding non intimate yichud? Does their level of loneliness factor into this? Does this situation allow any sexual activities not permitted in the previous scenario?
3.
Obviously intermarriage is completely forbidden in halacha.
Orthodox dating assumes that people are "currently OK". However some nonJews may be willing to date someone who is not doing emotionally great at the tine. The process of intimacy can be healing and in time, their emotional state may improve. (Obviously that doesn't mean that a relationship is an emotional cure all and there are many factors in play.)
We say that the Torah doesn't ask too much of people. People with autism are rejected by much of society, Jewish and non-Jewish. Yet they are expected not to intermarry, despite it being one of the few ways they have positive social interaction in their life. Furthermore, if the only people willing to socialize with them are a small subset of nonJews are they supposed to remain lonely?
It seems like such Jews are pushed hard in the direction of intermarriage. It seems that the Torah is asking too much. Unless you say that a lifetime of suffering, severe depression, and loneliness is not asking too much.
4.
Mental health can be hugely impacted by disability and disease. And physical pain too can cause depression. But social rejection is another big cause of negative mental health. If someone is in a situation of psychiatric pikuach nefesh because of all these things, are there sny halachic leniencies regarding sexual and intimate needs? For example a person may be long term suicidal but able to come out of it when they finally experience love from a non-Jew as well as a set of non Jewish friends who accept them for who they are with all the unusual traits of significant autism.
They may have to choose between their life and their status as an Orthodox Jew. This is not purely fictional as a countable number of formerly Orthodox Jews have been essentially excluded due to severe disability (typically multiple disabilities). Halacha sees suicide as essentially self murder and it is conceivable that it is better to do various typically forbidden practices rather than end one's own life due to foreseeable mental health problems that could be ameliorated.
NB: I'm asking assuming the scenarios I gave. In theory if we all were mekayem  ואהבת לרעך כמוך properly, many of these issues would be tremendously mitigated. But in the real world, some Jews with autism / developmental disabilities are bullied and excluded. Many are made to feel like they don't belong in klal Yisroel. So they have to take the world as it is, not as it should be. Maybe fixing this may help bring Moshiach.
Edit: this is not about the obligation to procreate which is asked elsewhere. It's about what heterim are available if someone cannot get married because they are unwanted. Even if one is not ready physically or psychologically to have children, one can and should get married according to another answer given. But what if one can't get married? How does a person deal with sexual needs and emotional intimacy meeds etc? And how does one negotiate the social rejection because of severe disability?

These all sound like very difficult situations, and anyone experiencing anything even remotely like this should really speak to a rabbi. Nevertheless, how is intermarriage a solution? There are plenty of frum and non-frum Jews living with these same conditions, why couldn't a person in this conundrum marry one of them?

I also fail to see why could intermarriage be a solution of the very serious scenarios you mention. Moreover, you seem to talk about two different things: marrying a non-Jew and having sexual relations with them – the two not being the same.

This question is similar to: Is someone who is physically or mentally disabled obligated to be fruitful and multiply. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My question is about options available for disabled people who can't get married. Do they have other halachic options? Can they do motzei zera etc? It isn't asking of they are chiyuv to have children which obviously os impossible of no one will marry them.

@Moshe  the answer to that question deals with the issue of "impossible to marry due to disability" and asks if that is even a thing.

@rabbikaii I saw your other post and the notion that marriage is important even if one shouldn't be having children. My question is what do you do when you cant get married to begin with?

@Moshe I have read it, and I can't see anything that "paturs" someone from marriage. I agree that the situations you've described are not "made up", but I still disagree with it being impossible to get married. I would encourage any person to try and try and try, and also educate them on the hashkafa of marriage, intimacy and relationships to help them with their mental health (so many issues are caused by misconceptions, especially when mixed with as one's own fears, worries, low self esteem and indeed, the stimgas you've mentioned). Also I would ask you to consider...1/2

...the situation of homosexual Jews. Their situation is very very similar - many cannot bring themselves to get married and have a Torah kosher relationship, and thus feel condemned to either sin, or live a life of loneliness and depression. The other answer I have given is also based around this case, and you can find sources to a good long halachic discussion, with heart, by Rav Melamed, regarding homosexual yidden and what they can/should and can't do. Ultimately it is crucial for such a person to speak to a good Rabbi, and I wish all such people much consolation and hatzlacha 2/2

@rabbikaii If you know of frum people who would agree to marry someone who has autism and a severe physical illness, then I'm truly amazed. The person can very badly want to get married but in reality there are no takers.

@Moshe I very much do. I even know someone who married a girl with terminal leukemia

@rabbikaii do you know of any girl sho was willing to marry a guy with significant autism and a painful chronic illness. It's harder when it's the guy who is "weak".

@Moshe I'm glad you put "weak" in quotes, because indeed such a person does not sound weak, and I've certainly known girls who would get that and admire such a person. This is getting too specific now, but I will say this: the gemara informs us that Hashem arranges our marriages, not us, and we have soul mates - people that we are destined to marry. We are permitted to leave all our doubts behind, and go and date, and daven that Hashem should make it successful, and there's no reason to presume He wont. The rare case of someone born without a soul mate is not connected to their health!

He can go to war and capture a yifas toar

@Moshe is there an issue with speaking to a Rabbi?

@Moshe I saw your msg before shabbat that you deleted. Have you tried being in touch with Chabad? They have a form on their website to be in touch with a Rabbi? If not lmk
